# Can Codility detect time complexity incorrectly?

Tags: c++, time-complexity

So I've been trying out the Codility and ended up with this piece of code:

```
int solution(vector<int> &A) 
{
   std::vector<int> min3(4);
   std::vector<int> max3(4);
   min3[0] = max3[2] = A[0];
   min3[1] = max3[1] = A[1];
   min3[2] = max3[0] = A[2];

   for(int i=3;i<A.size();i++)
   {
       min3[3] = max3[3] = A[i];
       std::sort(min3.begin(),min3.end());
       std::sort(max3.begin(),max3.end(),std::greater<int>());
   }

   return std::max(max3[0]*max3[1]*max3[2],max3[0]*min3[0]*min3[1]);
}
```

which, the way I see it, has a time complexity of O(N);
the Codility however [insists](https://codility.com/demo/results/trainingH4V5SG-MFP/) on O(N*log(N)) estimation. Could you please point out who is correct and why? Many thanks!

Comment: Why do you think that it is O(N)?  Do you think `std::sort` is free?

Comment: The sorting is performed on a vector of 4 elements, it can be considered as constant cost.

Comment: Ah stupid complex constants.  Also why are you calling sort twice on the same range?

Comment: @NathanOliver well they are not the same, 2 separate vectors of 4 elements to find 3 border elements on each side of an array; sorry if the code is unclear - I tried to make it simple to estimate the complexity, it could deteriorate the overall clearness of what it does:)

Comment: Ah yes.  those variable names looked a lot alike so my brain made them the same.  You may want to name them a little differently so it is really easy to see they are two separate objects.

Comment: Does `std::partial_sort` ([Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b2b7b4fc84d260a)) is seen as `N log N` solution ?

Comment: @Jarod42 well right, 'std::partial_sort' is the proper way to do it, and yes, the estimation [remains the same](https://codility.com/demo/results/trainingWB8HZB-7Y9/).
On a side note, dragging the A[0] multiplication out of the 'std::max()' kinda breaks the solution in case of fully negative input array

Comment: They may detect complexity according to there performance tests (and just expect `std::sort` instead of `partial_sort`).